# Inserting .txt into Excel via formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a formula to ask Excel to paste the content of a `.txt` file which contains several lines starting from specified cells, say file `C:/Folder/file1.txt` to be pasted in column `A` starting from cell `A3` downwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with a formula, but you can do it with VBA.  See this answer to [reading entire text file using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20390880/937094), which is copied below for your reference:

---

The following code will loop through each line in the text document and print these from range `H12` and downward in the UI-sheet.

```
Sub ImportFromText()
    Open "C:\tester.txt" For Input As #1
    r = 0
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, Data
        Worksheets("UI").Range("H12").Offset(r, 0) = Data
        r = r + 1
    Loop
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: ps: where do i get this vba? is it inside the excel starter 2010? tks

Comment: VBA is part of the full version of Excel.  Unfortunately, according to [Can I use VBA in Excel 2010 Starter Edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682527/can-i-use-vba-in-excel-2010-starter-edition) you have to upgrade to the Standard or Premium edition to be able to use VBA.